# In MySQL, when ordering by more than one conditions, how do I treat "false" the same way as "null"?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `select` statement where I want to order by a `boolean` column first, then order by a `date` column, and the goal is to put records with `boolean = true` at the top, then for the records with `boolean = false OR boolean is NULL`, they should be sorted by the `date` column`.

The statement is like

```sql
select *
from some_table
order by some_table.boolean_column desc, some_table.date_column desc
```

However, the issue is when a record's `boolean_column` is `false` (or `0`), it is not sorted by `date_column` with those whose `boolean_column` is `NULL`, because `0` is consider larger than `null`, so this record is places ahead of others whose `boolean_column` is `NULL`, though its `date_column` is not the most recent.

I want to treat `boolean_column = 0` the same way as `boolean_column is null`.

Could anyone teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an expression:

```
order by coalesce(some_table.boolean_column,0) desc, ...
```